# Japanese strings aren't bring correctly written to file

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to write a json dump of a list of objects to file.
The object looks like this:

```
class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, id, names, genus = None):
        self.id = id
        self.names = names

    def dict(self):
        return OrderedDict([("id", self.id), ("names", self.names)]) #force specific key order
```

`self.names` is a dictionary containing a language id and a corresponding name, some of them in Japanese, Korean and Chinese. Later on in my code, I save the list to JSON like this:

```
with codecs.open("pkmn.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    json.dump([p.dict() for p in pokemon], outfile, indent = 2)
```

But instead of "フシギダネ", "이상해씨", and "妙蛙種子", I get unreadable gibberish, as shown below.
[image: Screenshot of JSON file content]

How can I get Python to properly save those strings to file?

Comment: Uh... I don't know how to tell you this, but... that **is** JSON.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I do realize that this is JSON, but surely there must be some way to make it more readable.

Comment: Welp, I added `ensure_ascii = False` to my call to json.dump and it correctly saved all non-ASCII characters. I should just go to bed.